# Can't create a subversion repository with Eclipse 3.4.0, svn 1.5.1

Tags: eclipse, svn, macos

I'm working on `mac OS x 10.4`. I have a subversion repository stored on an external drive connected via USB. I created a new python project in `Eclipse` (using the PyDev plugin). When I use right click `Team->Share Project` to set up a new project with subversion, I get the following error:

```
Error while creating module: org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Couldn't open a repository
svn:  Unable to open ra_local session to URL
svn: Unable to open repository 'file:///Volumes/svn-repos/Palindrome/Palindrome'
```

The subversion repository has the following permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwx     9 cameronl  cameronl   306 Aug 23 10:08 svn-repos
```

The external drive is formatted as Mac OS extended

I'm completely stumped. Anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the repository first using the "SVN Repository Exploring" perspective (Window > Open Perspective > Other... > SVN Repository Exploring).

Make sure that the URL you are using points to the correct directory, which typically contains these default repository files:

```
conf/  dav/  db/  format  hooks/  locks/  README.txt
```

Hope this helps.